# iOS: Callback function after popViewControllerAnimated called?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a navigationcontroller with two view on storyboard.

In the first view I use this to navigate to the next (second) view:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController" sender:sender];
```

The segue style is push.

The second view has two top bar button, a back button which navigates back normally, and a custom right bar button, which do something on the background and after that navigates back with this code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Sometimes, when I call this code, I want to call a function (like as a callback function) in first view, which refresh some stuff on the first view.

How can I do that?

I try to use in the first view the viewWillAppear, but I don't want to refresh stuff every time, just sometimes.

Thanks!

**RESOLVED.**

I found the way to solve the problem:
When I use the prepareForSegue function, I can set the [segue destinationViewController] object's any property.

So I set a delegate property to the sender (fisrt) controller, and in the second controller, I can call [delegate anyFunction]

It is works, maybe it's a good solution... :-S

Answer (score 2):

Delegation should solve your problem. Make the first view controller the delegate of the second and send it a message when you dismiss the view controller.

Comment: It's ok, and I tried, but not works. I use this: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/delegates/how-to-create-a-delegate

In my project, MainClass is the firstview, Subclass is the second. But probably I can't observe perfectly the example... :)

Comment: So with navigation controller I navigate from the first viewcontroller to the second, and after that I navigate back from the second to the first, BUT, when I call the navigate back function in second viewcontroller, I have an IF statement about "should I need call a function in first view after the navigate back is done?", and even if the statement was true, I want to call the function in the first controller. But the statement is in the second view controller.
Sorry for my bad english, I hope it's understandable.